# HBase table ??? doesn't exist while the table is declared as an external table

Tags: hive, hbase, hadoop2

I'm trying to create a HBase table using Hive (which I am intending to fill it from another Hive table using insert), through the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HBWeather (key struct<USAF:INT, WBAN:INT, `Date`:STRING>, TEMP INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '~' 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,T:Temp');
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:MetaException(message:HBase table hbweather doesn't exist while the table is declared as an external table.)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:154)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:830)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
)
```

**What is the problem exactly? and how to fix it?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The "location" component of your command to create the external table is missing. Since you specified "external" you must specify a filesystem path on HDFS where Hive will create the table. That is the error reported on the 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Hbase table first then and append below property in the HQL.

*tblproperties ("hbase.table.name"= "/path to table HBWeather")*